# Set DependencyProperty on Initialization of an element?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

How can I set `DependencyProperty` on Initialization of an element??

```
new DataGrid() { FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(DataGrid_Obj,true)};
```

It is giving me following error :

[image]

If I write like this :

```
DataGrid DataGrid_Obj = new DataGrid() { FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(DataGrid_Obj,true)};
```

Then it is giving me :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384261%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you can just perform assignments to properties or fields in initializer. Commands like your `FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(DataGrid_Obj,true)` have to be called after constructing and initializing your object.

Besides you can't use the `DataGrid_Obj` in its own initializer at all because it is created not before the constructor is done (of course). So it will be `null`.

Just write

```
DataGrid DataGrid_Obj = new DataGrid();
FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(DataGrid_Obj,true);
```

So I think it should work. (I didn't try it.)